# Storing different types of data in a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have to create a doubly linked list that can store different types of data (in fact, I need to make a small program in which the name of the plant, plant class, plant family will be stored).  In general, I already made a doubly-linked list, but earlier only decimal numbers were stored there.  When I wanted to store whole sentences instead of numbers - there was a problem.

here is an example code:
(and yes, I'm a foreign student, and our teachers require comments in our native language, so sorry for the inconvenience)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <locale>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
//template <typename A>//создаем тип

typedef struct Node // создание узла двусвязного списка
{
public:
    char plant[100];       //информационое поле
    Node* Next, * Prev;  //указатели на адреса началаспискаи конца
};

class List // создаемтип данных список
{
    Node* Head;

public:
    List() {
        Head = NULL; // изначально список пустой
    }
    void create(char x);
    void show();
    void add_begin(char x);
    void add_end(char x);
    void add_after(char x, int position);
    void delete_(char x);

};

void List::create(char x) // функция создания листа, поочерёдно добавляя элементы
{
    if (Head != NULL) {// если списщк не пустой- возращаемся
        cout << "The list already created." << endl;
        return;
    }
    else {
        //Node* h, * temp;
        Node* temp = new Node;
        Node* h = new Node;
        temp = new(Node);
        temp->plant = x;
        temp->Next = NULL;
        temp->Prev = NULL;
        Head = temp;
        cout << "action completed" << endl;
    }

}

void List::add_end(char x)
{
    Node* temp = new(Node); // создаем новый елемент ,
    temp->Next = NULL;    // следующего елемента нет
    temp->plant = x;     // заполняем данные
    if (Head == NULL) // если список пустой -   добавляем первый элемент в список
    {
        temp->Prev = NULL;
        Head = temp;
    }
    else {

        Node* h = Head;
        while (h->Next != NULL)
            h = h->Next;
        h->Next = temp;
        temp->Prev = h;
    }
    cout << "action completed" << endl;
}

void List::add_begin(char x)
{
    Node* temp = new(Node); // создание нового узла, выставление ссылок

    temp->Prev = NULL;    // предыдущего елемента не существует
    temp->plant = x;        // заполняем данные
    temp->Next = Head;     // следующий елемент - бывший head
    if (Head == NULL) //  если список пустой- то добавляем первый елемент
    {
        temp->Prev = NULL;
        Head = temp;
    }
    else {
        Head->Prev = temp;
        Head = temp;
    }
    cout << "action completed" << endl; // действие выполнено
}
void List::add_after(char x, int y)
{
    if (Head == NULL) // есть ли один узел?
    {
        cout << "First сreate the list." << endl;
        return;
    }
    Node* tmp, * h = Head;
    for (int i = 0; i < y - 1; i++)
    {
        h = h->Next;
        if (h == NULL) // проверка, есть ли элемент в списке
        {
            cout << "There are less than " << y << " elements." << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    tmp = new(Node); // создание нового узла
    tmp->plant = x;       // заполняем данные
    if (h->Next == NULL) // если послн елемента - ноль , то указатели выставлчем длч следующего елемента
    {
        h->Next = tmp;
        tmp->Next = NULL;     // слудующего елемента не существует
        tmp->Prev = h;         // предидущий - голова
    }
    else // если после елемента не идет ноль то тоже выставляем соответствующие указатели
    {
        tmp->Next = h->Next;
        tmp->Next->Prev = tmp;
        h->Next = tmp;
        tmp->Prev = h;
    }
    cout << "action completed" << endl;
}

void List::delete_(char x)
{
    Node* tmp, * h;
    if (Head == NULL) // емли нет не одного узла, то возращаемся
    {
        cout << "List empty,nothing to delete" << endl;
        return;
    }
    if (Head->plant == x)     //удаляем первый елемент
    {
        tmp = Head;
        Head = Head->Next;  // теперь голова -это следующий елемент
        Head->Prev = NULL;   // предыдущего не существует
        cout << "Element Deleted" << endl;
        free(tmp);
        return;
    }
    h = Head;
    while (h->Next->Next != NULL)
    {

        if (h->Next->plant == x)    // удаляем елемент после
        {
            tmp = h->Next;
            h->Next = tmp->Next;
            tmp->Next->Prev = h;
            cout << "Element Deleted" << endl;
            free(tmp);
            return;
        }
        h = h->Next;
    }
    if (h->Next->plant == x) // удаление последнего елемента
    {
        tmp = h->Next;
        free(tmp);
        h->Next = NULL;      //следующего не существует
        cout << "Element Deleted" << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "Element " << x << " not found" << endl;
}



void List::show()
{
    Node* h = Head;
    if (Head == NULL) // если нет не одного узла, то возращаемся
    {
        cout << "List empty,nothing to display" << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "The Doubly Link List is :" << endl;
    while (h != NULL) //пока голова не будет равняться нулю роказывать даные
    {
        cout << h->plant << endl;
        h = h->Next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ukr");
    int choice,  position;
    char element;
    List b;
    while (222)
    {                             //действия которые можно использовать
        cout << "****" << endl;
        cout << "1(Створити список)" << endl;
        cout << "2(Додати елемент в початок)" << endl;
        cout << "3(Додати елемент в кiнець)" << endl;
        cout << "4(Додати пiсля елемента)" << endl;
        cout << "5(Видалити)" << endl;
        cout << "6(Показати список)" << endl;
        cout << "7(Вийти)" << endl;
        cout << " Вибершть дiю : ";
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Введiть значення: ";
            cin >> element;
            b.create(element);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Введiть значення: ";
            cin >> element;
            b.add_begin(element);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Введiть значення: ";
            cin >> element;
            b.add_end(element);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Введiть значення: ";
            cin >> element;
            cout << "Введiть елемент пiсля якого додати: ";
            cin >> position;
            b.add_after(element, position);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "Введiть  елемент для значення: ";
            cin >> element;
            b.delete_(element);
            cout << endl;
            break;

        case 6:
            b.show();
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 7:
            cout << "Завершення" << endl;
            exit(222);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? You have commented out `//template <typename A>`, but this seems to be what you want. Using templates you can store any kind of data, including structures containing multiple members.

Comment: Also, if you can use a `std::string`, this will be easier.

Comment: Did you want to store different types of data in the _same_ list?  If so, check out `std::variant`.